# zle - I cannot find why Ctrl+R does not work for non-root

Tags: zsh, line-editor

The <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> works for root (well toor) however I cannot find why it does not work for user.

User `.zshrc`:

```
setopt AUTO_CD
setopt CORRECT_ALL
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
# History
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh/history
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
setopt NO_HIST_BEEP
setopt SHARE_HISTORY
# Keys
autoload zkbd
[[ ! -d ~/.zkbd ]] && mkdir ~/.zkbd
[[ ! -f ~/.zkbd/$TERM-${DISPLAY:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE} ]] && zkbd
source  ~/.zkbd/$TERM-${DISPLAY:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE}
[[ -n ${key[Home]}    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
[[ -n ${key[End]}     ]]  && bindkey  "${key[End]}"     end-of-line
[[ -n ${key[Insert]}  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Insert]}"  overwrite-mode
[[ -n ${key[Delete]}  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Delete]}"  delete-char
[[ -n ${key[Up]}      ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Up]}"      up-line-or-history
[[ -n ${key[Down]}    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Down]}"    down-line-or-history
[[ -n ${key[Left]}    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Left]}"    backward-char
[[ -n ${key[Right]}   ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Right]}"   forward-char
# Auto completion
autoload -U compinit promptinit
compinit
promptinit
prompt clint
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache 1
setopt HASH_LIST_ALL
# MIME
autoload -U zsh-mime-setup
zsh-mime-setup
# Calc
autoload -U zcalc
# Login
alias su="su - toor"
```

diff with root .zshrc:

```
--- -   2011-01-06 23:53:54.772440701 +0100
+++ .zshrc  2011-01-06 23:50:00.000000000 +0100
@@ -38,9 +38,5 @@
 zsh-mime-setup
 # Calc
 autoload -U zcalc
-# Editor
-export EDITOR=vim
-# Paludis
-alias background="schedtool -B -e"
-alias lowprio="nice -n 20 ionice -c 3"
-alias blowprio="ionice -c 3 schedtool -B -e nice -n 20"
+# Login
+alias su="su - toor"
```

Any ideas?

zsh version 2.3.11.

Comment: ^r is search right. in vi mode use  enter command mode, and type / then search paramenter, enter, n or N to go forward and backwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have `$EDITOR = vi*` or `VISUAL = vi*` when zsh starts up, zsh uses vi insertion mode as the default keymap. Otherwise zsh uses emacs mode. You presumably set `EDITOR` (or `VISUAL`) to `vim` in your init file, but have no such setting when running as root, so you're seeing the vi mode map, in which history search is on `^X r` and `^X s`.

Add `bindkey -e` to your `.zshrc` (or learn the vi map).

As usual, this is in the documentation (`zshzle` man page), but you have to know what you're looking for.

Comment: I read documentation on the web but it did not appear in placed I looked at.